# google search in my website

Tags: search

Is it legal to use the google search results in my own website not using the google custom search that google provides?

I have 2 different cases:

The first is that I design a search box, with a google logo and provide options so the user selects which type of content (web, images, videos...), and the the results open in a new window with the normal google search results page. it means I submit the the search query from my website to the google search results.

The second is that I design both the search box and the results page so that the results are shown in my website instead of the google search results page.
I found an example for this:
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/09/google-powered-site-search-ajax-jquery/search.html

NB: In both of the cases I will include a google logo and link to the original google.com website as credit.

So which of the two cases or are they both legal?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that they are. The google ajax search api allows you to embed a search into your page using an iframe i believe. Look at the http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/terms.html for the api's

Comment: thanks for the link controlfreak123 it looks very helpful but I think this will take me the whole night to read and get something interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the Google AJAX API for your purposes. See:

[Am I allowed to use the Google AJAX Search API on my site?](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxsearch/faq/#allowedToUse)

Google also provides [documentation for developers](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/) and [example code](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxsearch/samples.html).

For the legality of specific uses, you should refer to [Google AJAX Search API Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/ajaxsearch/terms.html) and a lawyer. Good thing you said you don't want to use custom search, because the [Google Custom Search Terms of service](http://www.google.com/cse/docs/tos.html) seem to specifically exclude using it with new windows and within frames in sections 1.4(b) and 1.4(c).